# Onclick Listeners in Android

Tags: android

assume that i have three buttons all of whose listeners point to (this) . So if I press any of the button is it going to start from the beginning of the activity, irrespective of the button pressed?

Answer (score 3):

No, it will go on override method `onClick()` of your Activity.

```
listeners point to (this)
```

you must have to implements onClickListener to your activity which will override `onClick()`

To verify which view had been clicked, you have to do something like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v== controlName)
       // controlName is clicked
}
```

Comment: Oh.... Got It Mate Thanx... I can use view.getID() to differentiate the buttons rite? In that case are these button ID's going to be same in all Devices?

Comment: You define the IDs in the layout XML.  Or, assign them programatically, so yes, always the same.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use a switch case and get to know what's the button clicked.

try this:

```
class stuff extends Activity implements onClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this); 
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
             // do something
             break;
        case R.id.button2:
             // do something else
             break;
        case R.id.button3:
             // do yet another thing
             break;
        default:
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Confusing question...

Anyway, here it goes an listener example .

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
   private Button firstBtn;
   private Button secondBtn;
   private Button thirdBtn;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    firstBtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstBtn);
    secondBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondBtn);
    thirdBtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdBtn); 

    firstBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("MyClass", "first button clicked!");
        }
    });

    secondBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("MyClass", "second button clicked!");
        }
    });

    thirdBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("MyClass", "third button clicked!");
        }
    });
   }
```

}

Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but the code you written is sloppy and has poor readability. having an anonymus listener for each button instead of taking care of the listener in the activity scope makes the code un-maintainable...

Comment: Sure that all makes sense. But all depends on the context, anonymous listeners can be perfectly accept on simple, on-liners. And has less overhead i might add.

Comment: Thanx for the example... didnt know it can be done this way. But again it depends on the context... for me an if else worked out...

Comment: @bmartins, I think your version has more overhead than mine. switch statements are the equivalent to `GOTO` and have almost no overhead, but creating a separate listener for each button takes more memory and there for is less efficient than having a pointer to the same listener.